# update batch in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have data on `db_temporary` here I will update based on `id_service`, but why doesn't the update work?

```
public function updateUpload() {
    $db = $this->M_order->db_temporary_service(); //db_temporary
    $data = array();

    foreach($db AS $key => $val){

        $data[] = array(
            "id_service"         => $_POST['id_service'][$key],
            "id_destination"     => $_POST['id_destination'][$key],
            "id_sub_destination" => $_POST['id_sub_destination'][$key],
            "charges_order"      => $_POST['charges_order'][$key],
            "weight_order"       => $_POST['weight_order'][$key],
            "jenis_service"      => $_POST['jenis_service'][$key],
            "service_order"      => $_POST['service_order'][$key],
            "charges_order"      => $_POST['charges_order'][$key],
         );

         echo '<pre>', print_r($data);

         //update to db_service where id_service
         $this->db->update_batch('service', $data, 'id_service');

         redirect('backend/.....');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data doesn't seem to be updated because you've used `update_batch` as well as `redirect` inside `foreach` loop, I'm writing the rectified code below, comments are mentioned wherever necessary. See if it resolves your issue.

```
public function updateUpload(){
        $db = $this->M_order->db_temporary_service(); //db_temporary
        $data = array();
        foreach($db AS $key => $val){

            $data[] = array(
                "id_service"              => $_POST['id_service'][$key],
                "id_destination"          => $_POST['id_destination'][$key],
                "id_sub_destination"      => $_POST['id_sub_destination'][$key],
                "charges_order"           => $_POST['charges_order'][$key],
                "weight_order"            => $_POST['weight_order'][$key],
                "jenis_service"           => $_POST['jenis_service'][$key],
                "service_order"           => $_POST['service_order'][$key],
                "charges_order"           => $_POST['charges_order'][$key],
               );
        }
        // echo '<pre>', print_r($data); // all the data should be here
        $this->db->update_batch('service', $data, 'id_service'); // update the table with all the data
        redirect('backend/.....');
    }
```

Comment: so where is the fault?

Comment: compare both the codes, they're different. @HarryWardana